# Pass variable to main function Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, cheerio

Basically I'm trying to pass the "Browser" variable on to my main function, to pass on to "CheckStock". I've tried many thing but just can't seem to find a way how to do this. If anyone knows how to, please let me know. Thanks in advance! :)

```
// STARTUP BROWSER & GO TO URL
async function openBrowser(monitorURL) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(monitorURL)
  return browser, page;
}

/* 
...
...
...
other code
...
...
...
*/

// MAIN FUNCTION
async function monitor(monitorURL){
  const page  = await openBrowser(monitorURL);
  await checkStock(page, browser)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change how you return the two values to this (so they are both available in a returned object):

```
async function openBrowser(monitorURL) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(monitorURL)
  return {browser, page};
}
```

And, then how you get them both out of that object:

```
// MAIN FUNCTION
async function monitor(monitorURL){
  const {page, browser} = await openBrowser(monitorURL);
  await checkStock(page, browser);
}
```